# How to print a pointer pointing to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, printing

I'm using this code

```
char *p=NULL;
char *sk="hello";
p=&sk;
printf("%s",p);
```

I wanted to print hello but instead I take the address(or symbols in case of %s).
 How do I fix that?

Comment: Don't print pointers, except for debugging. Printing them is useless and non-portable. Pointer addresses are often non reproducible, because of [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p = &sk; // put the address of pointer sk in p
```

**Note that this is illegal! The type of `p` is `char*`; the type of `&sk` is `char**`. These types are not compatible. Your compiler should have warned you about the assignment between incompatible types.**

Turn on all your compiler warnings and mind them!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
char **p=NULL; 
char *sk="hello"; 
p=&sk; // p should be a pointer-to-pointer to char
printf("%s",*p);
```

or

```
char *p=NULL; 
char *sk="hello"; 
p=sk; 
printf("%s",p);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p = &sk;
```

The above statement assigns the address of `sk` into `p`, which needs `p` to be a `char **`, but in your original code, `p` is a `char *`, hence the **assignment of `p` and `sk` is illegal**.

Things you could do:

1. Assign `p` to `sk`. Change your code to:

   ```
   p = sk;
   printf("%s",p);
   ```
2. Change `p` to `char **` and then assign `p` the address of pointer `sk`.

   ```
   char **p;
   p = &sk;
   printf("%s",*p); //Prints the string pointed by the char **p
   ```